# Compilation error in AnyPoint Studio

Tags: compiler-errors, mule, mule-studio

When I try to use `java.util.List` or `java.util.Map` as parameters in methods annotated with `@Processor`, I get the following compilation error:

> Internal compiler error: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>       com/sun/tools/javac/util/Name at
>       org.mule.devkit.apt.JavaCompilerUtils.getJava16Names
>       (JavaCompilerUtils.java:31)

Does someone know how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is an issue caused because the plugin was trying to pick up classes from JDK 6 while using JDK7.

This was fixed in the latest released version of mule Studio October 2014 Release and the Anypoint DevKit plugin